# Comparing big powers

Tags: contest-math, exponentiation, number-comparison

> Which of the following is the largest?
>
> A. $1^{200}$
>
> B. $2^{400}$
>
> C.$4^{80}$
>
> D. $6^{300}$
>
> E. $10^{250}$

I'm stuck trying to solve this. Obviously A and C are wrong ($4^{80}$ is less than $2^{400}$ and 1 to any power is always 1). And cancelling $2^{200}$ from each of the remaining choices, I can also eliminate B. However, I don't really know how to compare D and E... Any hints or helps?

Comment: $6^{300}=(6^{3})^{100}$ 6^3=216 and is less then $(3\cdot 100)^{100}=3^{100}\cdot (10)^{100}$, now $3^{100}=9^{50}<10^{50}$. So you we get $6^{300}<10^{150}<10^{250}$. If i have made no mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$6^{300} = (6^6)^{50} \ \ ; \ \ 10^{250} = (10^5)^{50}$$
so it is enough to check what is larger between $6^6$ and $10^5$. Now,
$$6^6 = (6^3)^2 = 216^2 < 300^2 = 90000 < 100000 = 10^5$$

Answer (score 1):

$$10^{250}>6^{300}$$ or
$$10^5>6^6$$ or
$$5^5>2\cdot3^6$$ or
$$3125>1458,$$
which is obvious.

Now, it's obvious that $10^{250}$ is a largest number.

Comment: it's more elegant to continue mathematically ( witjhout computing I mean...) from here. $ 5^5>2\cdot3^6 $

Comment: @Isham I made it without computer. I knew that $5^5=3125$ and $3^6=729$. I found the following solution for you: $5^5>12\cdot5^3=6\cdot250>6\cdot3^5=2\cdot3^6$

Answer (score 1):

$$ 10^{250}>6^{300} $$
$$ 10^{5}>6^{6} $$
$$ 5^{5} 2^{5}>2^{6} 3^{6}$$
$$ 5^{5} >2.3^{6}$$

Note that $ 3^2=9<10=5.2 $ so:

$$ 2.3^{6} < 2.10.10.10=2.10^3=2^4.5^3 $$
$$ 2.3^{6} < 2^4.5^3 < 5^5 $$
$$ 2^4 < 5^2 $$
$$ 4^2 < 5^2 $$

Answer (score 0):

B is $2^{400}$

D is $2^{300}3^{300} \gt 2^{600}$

E is $10^{250} =2^{250}5^{250}$

Then we have $3^6=729, 5^5=3125\gt2^23^6$

So E is $10^{250} =2^{250}5^{250}\gt2^{250}(2^23^6)^{50}=2^{350}3^{300}\gt 2^{300}3^{300}$

Answer (score -1):

$$2^{400} = 1024^{40} < 10000^{40} = 10^{160} < 10^{250}$$

See the other answers for $6^{300}$ and $10^{250}$.